# How to change memory allocation for cloud function when deploying by gcloud command

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud

When deploying a cloud function, I'm using command like this.

```
gcloud functions deploy MyCloudFunction --runtime nodejs8 --trigger-http
```

Default memory allocation is 256MB. I changed it 1GB using Google cloud console from browser.
Is there a way to change memory allocation when deploying by `gcloud` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read over the [CLI documentation for `gcloud functions deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy).

You can use the [--memory](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--memory) flag to set the memory:

```
gcloud functions deploy MyCloud Functions ... --memory 1024MB
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to increase the CPU count to be able to increase memory beyond 512 MiB. Otherwise, with the default 0.33 vCPU Cloud Function allocation, I saw errors like the following, where `[SERVICE]` is the name of your Google Cloud Function below:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Could not update Cloud Run service [SERVICE]. spec.template.spec.containers[0].resources.limits.memory: Invalid value specified for container memory. For 0.333 CPU, memory must be between 128Mi and 512Mi inclusive.
```

From https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu#command-line, this can be done by calling `gcloud run services update [SERVICE] --cpu [CPU]`, for example:

```
gcloud run services update [SERVICE] --cpu=4 --memory=16Gi --region=northamerica-northeast1
```

You should see a response like:

```
Service [SERVICE] revision [SERVICE-*****-***] has been deployed and is serving 100 percent of traffic.
```

https://console.cloud.google.com/run can help show what is happening too.